# Search low values in mainframe files

Tags: sed, grep, awk

I am working with mainframe files and it seems that the low values (x'00') exists in the records in the file which throws off my import for fixed block.

Does anyone know how to eliminate those characters in Linux?

Comment: Eliminate - you just want to delete them? or replace with sometihng?

Comment: What do you mean by "low values `x'00'`? The NUL character? What kind of files, any special format to them? What "mainframe" application did create them?

Comment: `0x00` is used by various programs to delimiter values that can contain any character. E.g. a filename in Linux can have a newline character. To make a fool-proof list of filenames one would use `0x00` as separator and not `\n`. Thus a bit more context, as @vonbrand asks for could probably give a more usable answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delete NUL characters, a proggie like this does the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        int c;

        while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
                if(c)
                        putchar(c);

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: There is already a program for stripping nul bytes: `tr -d '\0' < infile > outfile`